# How to add a onclick function on every Datatable Table tr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I am using datatable using ajax calling and the script for datatable is like -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    });
});
```

and every row is showing like - `"<tr role="row" class="even">"`

But i need to put a onlcick function every datatable rows like - `"<tr ondblclick="getDetails(id)" role="row" class="even">"`

so how can i do that any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post console errors if any

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make a jquery on click event on the class "even".. But to recieve an ID you will need to have either an id or a data-id on each row to know which id you want to use..

```
<tr role="row" class="even" data-id="1">
<tr role="row" class="even" data-id="2">

$(".even, .odd").on("click", function() {
   var id = $(this).data("id); or $(this).id(); // need to check what rowId does
   alert("test"); or alert(id);
   getDetails(id);
});
```

you can set an id by doing something like this:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ],
    rowId: 'staffId' //staffID has to be given from you
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help but  I am finding a problem that no jQuery event (like click, dblclick,onclick) are not working for my datatable, any idea why ?

Comment: sorry, i made a ":" instead of ";" in my onclick function.. also I've seen datatables has "even" and "odd" rows, so you have to change $(".even.") to $(".even, .odd") so that it works for both.. just try alert("test"); instead of var id .... and getDetails and see if that works..

Answer (score 6):

As seen at [this site](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html) you can do

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
} );
```

or dblclick

```
$('#example tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    alert( 'You double clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
} );
```

Comment: Please post your source: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html

Comment: Thanks for help but  I am finding a problem that no jQuery event (like click, dblclick,onclick) are not working for my datatable, any idea why ?

Comment: Thanks , it works

Answer (score 1):

jquery datatable have an already click event for your need

you can do this by using simple way taken from [this site](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html)

1) If you want event for single click on row

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        var data = table.row( this ).data();
        alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
    } );
} );
```

2) If you want event for double click on row

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        $('#example tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
            var data = table.row( this ).data();
            alert( 'You clicked on '+data[0]+'\'s row' );
        } );
    } );
```

Comment: This looks like a copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/51374242/295783 just wrapped in a ready. - it is called plagiarism and is poor form

Comment: @mplungjan , No I already used in my project and for your reference I refer this

[link](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/events_live.html) to implement it in my existing project

Comment: Then there are two plagiarisms here. You also did not credit the source

Comment: @mplungjan, means we both are adding answer to this question on same time and your answer is posted before my. otherwise i dont post same answer that you posted.

Comment: It was not mine. - and yours was indeed 4 minutes later than the same answer

Comment: @mplungjan, I am late to post my answer bcoz i tried to search the answer it in my project

Comment: No problem. Just please credit the site you take your code from

Comment: Yes i already added a link in my previous comment

Comment: See where I put it for you. That’s where it belongs

Comment: yes your right here i also used it in my project from same link that you edited. thanks for improving my answer :)